# Appcelerator Titanium Slider

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am new to the whole Appcelerator world so I had a question:

Anybody is aware if appcelerator titanium provides slider functionality similar to this screenshot?

If not, what would be the first docs to look at?

No need for fancy animation or anything, just simplest transition.

[image]

I just need basic slider for titanium that has slide selectors looking like small circles (or something I could modify or adjust to custom needs).

Also, yes I'll use this as a startpoint
http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Slider-object

But the page doesn't have screenshots of how the slider object looks and acts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the ScrollableView control, with the paging component enabled.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView-object

Comment: Thank you, I already did it manually but next time I'll use it. Or may be rewrite my code...

Answer (score 1):

For displaying such kind of progresbar or slider u have to create custom view and inside that custom view put as many as dots images as you have photos and just scrolling of each photos change dots image as per e.current / e.views ...

and set previous image to default image. and make it touch enabled = false.

Answer (score 1):

ScrollableView control, with the paging.

[link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView-object)